# How do I sent data from options.js to content.js using storage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm a JavaScript beginner and for my first project I thought I'd write a useful chrome extension, however, I'm stuck on how to send data from my chrome extensions options page to the javascript that's being run the page.
In `options.js`.
I've managed to successfully add and retrieve values from the storage by using:
`chrome.storage.local.set(obj)` 
 
`chrome.storage.local.get(obj)`
It works fine as long as I'm storing and retrieving in the same js file - `options.js`.
I've copied the same block that retrieves the values from `options.js` into `content.js`, however the value always appears as `undefined` in the chrome js debugger. For the life of me, I don't know how to set the value in `options.js` and retrieve it in `content.js`

What am I doing wrong? Can I not run `chrome.storage.local.set(obj)` in `options.js` and then run `chrome.storage.local.get(obj)` in `content.js` to pull the values?
Here is a code snippet to show you what I'm doing:
the text box id is `name`, in
`options.js`:

```
function saveTextbox(txtboxId) {
  var theValue = document.getElementById(txtboxId).value;
  var obj = {};
  obj[txtboxId] = theValue;
  storage.set(obj);
}
```

in `content.js`:

```
function getValue(textboxId) {
  storage.get(textboxId, function(result) {
    return result.name;
  });
}
```

Any advice on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of returning the value inside storage.get, just use it there. The API is asynchronous so the callback is invoked at a later point in the future, it's basically a one-time listener for an "on-read" event from the storage.

Comment: See also [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)

Comment: The problem is if I run `console.log(result.name);` in `options.js` it'll print `hello world` but in `content.js` it'll return `undefined` - I don't understand why this is happening. Is the storage not shared between both js files? `content.js` runs on the page, `options.js` is running in the chrome extensions options tab.

Comment: The storage is shared. I don't see where exactly you have console.log so I can't say what's wrong for sure. Most likely it's outside of the callback which is wrong as explained above.

Comment: Ahh yes you're right. I got it working, thanks so much!!  i just had to update `return` with `console.log()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @wOxxOm, I now understand that is an async call and that's why this wasn't working:

```
function getValue(textboxId) {
  storage.get(textboxId, function(result) {
    return result.name; << this is the problem
  });
}
```